# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Removing nan from list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, nan

I need to remove `nan` values from python list. The problem is that the list can contain lists of one element, lists of two elements or nan values. E.g.:

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [[1,2],float('nan'),[8],[6],float('nan')]
print(mylist)
newlist = [x for x in mylist if not np.isnan(x)]
print(newlist)
```

Unfortunately calling np.isnan() on list with more than 1 element gives error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

The same goes for `pandas.isnull`

`math.isnan()` on the other hand gives:

> TypeError: must be real number, not list

Is there a short way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot test the NaN status on a list. You should only test is on floats.

For this you can use:

```
newlist = [x for x in mylist if not isinstance(x, float) or not np.isnan(x)]
```

alternatively:

```
newlist = [x for x in mylist if isinstance(x, list) or not np.isnan(x)]
```

Due to [short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), the `np.isnan(x)` will only be evaluated if x **is** a float (or not a list in the alternative), which won't trigger an error.

output: `[[1, 2], [8], [6]]`